# SQL: finding (multiple) best students of a professor by grade

Tags: sql, group-by

I have to find the students with the best grade of each professor with this given table "x":

| Prof | Student | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1.0 |
| A | 2 | 1.0 |
| A | 5 | 5.0 |
| A | 6 | 1.3 |
| B | 3 | 1.2 |
| B | 4 | 2.0 |
| ... | ... | ... |

The result should look like this:

| Prof | Student | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1.0 |
| A | 2 | 1.0 |
| B | 3 | 1.2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I already tried grouping the first table by Prof with:

```
SELECT Prof, Student, MIN(Grade)
FROM x
GROUP BY Prof
```

But the result gives me only one Student per professor like this:

| Prof | Student | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1.0 |
| B | 3 | 1.2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

So student 2 - who is also professor A's best student - is missing. How do I fix this?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? You should aways tag your SQL requests with the DBMS in question. Two possibilities here: Either your query is invalid or you are working in SQLIte. That is, you group by prof and tell the DBMS to select the professor's student. But a professor doesn't only have one student. So which student are you talking of? If it is SQLite you are using, the query is indeed valid, because SQLite guarantees to pick the student from a row with a minimum grade. In any other DBMS the query is invalid.

Comment: If it is MySQL you are working with, make sure not to work in cheat mode, but in ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY mode (via `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';`) in order to get an error on such invalid queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ave two possibilities

Once you select the minimum of grades for every professor and use tat as  resilset fpr an IN clause.

```
SELECT Prof, Student, Grade
FROM x
WHERE  (Prof,  Grade) IN (SELECT Prof,  MIN(Grade)
FROM x
GROUP BY Prof)
```

Or as joined table, which is on big table usually faster

```
SELECT Prof, Student, Grade
FROM x JOIN
(SELECT Prof,  MIN(Grade) mingrade
FROM x
GROUP BY Prof) t1 x.prof = t1.prof AND x.Grade = t1.mingrade
```

Comment: This will not return _the students with the best grade of each professor_.

Comment: you are right i corrected my misstake

Comment: The explanation ("You need to group by the two columns") is still wrong. It should be something like "You need two steps: first get the best grades per professor, then get the professors' students with these grades". I prefer the first query for its readabilty, btw.

Comment: i correected also te explanation thank you

Comment: I used the second approach and it worked great for me. Thanks a lot!